# Apply function to embedded tibble

Tags: r, dplyr, tibble

I've a tibble with 5 columns as :

```
# A tibble: 13 x 5
   sample animal   RNA  type              fusion
    <chr>  <int> <chr> <chr>              <list>
 1      A    206 meth1    T3 <tibble [126 x 24]>
 2      B    206 meth1    T5 <tibble [650 x 24]>
 3      C    206 meth1    T3 <tibble [515 x 24]>
 4      D    206 meth1    T5  <tibble [90 x 24]>
 5      E    206 meth1    T3 <tibble [154 x 24]>
 6      F    206 meth2    T5 <tibble [182 x 24]>
 7      G    206 meth2    T3 <tibble [148 x 24]>
 8      H    206 meth2    T5 <tibble [500 x 24]>
 9      I    206 meth2    T3  <tibble [50 x 24]>
10      J    206 meth2    T5  <tibble [16 x 24]>
11      K    212 meth2    T3   <tibble [3 x 24]>
12      L    212 meth2    T5   <tibble [3 x 24]>
13      M    212 meth2    T3   <tibble [1 x 24]>
```

I want to apply a function to each variable in the fusion column (an embedded tibble). The tibbles in the fusion columns contains the following columns :

vtype and unspecific_fusion :

I would like to apply this line :

```
x %>% group_by(vtype) %>% 
    summarise(n=sum(unspecific_fusion>0))
```

to each tibble in the fusion column (so one per line).

Any idea. I tried with map() and do() but I always have an error..

Thanks

P.S. :

In base R I could use

```
lapply(samplesheet$fusion,function(x){x %>% 
        group_by(vtype) %>% 
        summarise(n=sum(unspecific_fusions>0))})
```

but I would like to have a dplyr solution to be consistent with its use.

Comment: `unnest` and `nest` again...? If you provide reproducible example we can probably help you more

Comment: I was thinking something like `library(tidyverse); spreadsheet %>% mutate(fusion = map(fusion, function(x) {x %>% group_by(vtype) %>% summarise(n = sum(unspecific_fusions > 0))})` might work if you wanted to avoid unnesting. Although like Sotos says it's easier to help if you can provide a reproducible example to work with